# Java Font Rendering: Must general AA really be turned off for subpixel AA?

Tags: java, fonts, rendering, antialiasing

I have been attempting to enhance my GUI system written in Java to use subpixel antialiasing and have been successful, except for one remaining anomaly. This is a follow on to [my other question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018102/java-font-rendering).

The remaining problem is that setting rendering hints KEY_ANTIALIASING to VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON causes KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING to be ignored when it is set to an LCD (subpixel) AA value. Can anyone shed some light on this? Currently I am forced to VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF before rendering text and turn it back on after rendering text (so that other painting, like circles, etc, is AA'd).

This problem is proven by the self-contained test program below.  As you can see if you run it, the circle is painted with AA when the font isn't, and vice versa.  It would be nice to have AA preconfigured to work for all painting.

---

### Self Contained Test Program

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AwtTestFrame1c extends Panel {

AwtTestFrame1c() {
    setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    }

public void paint(Graphics gc) {
    Graphics2D                          g2d = (Graphics2D)gc;
    int                                 py=0;

    py=paintText(g2d,py,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB,true );
    py=paintText(g2d,py,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB,false);
    }

private int paintText(Graphics2D dgc, int py, Object val, boolean aa) {
    char[]                              txt=("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog ("+val+", General AA: "+aa+")").toCharArray();

    if(aa        ) { dgc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON ); }
    else           { dgc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF); }
    if(val !=null) { dgc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,val);                           }
    dgc.setFont(font);

    dgc.drawOval(5,py+5,15,15);
    dgc.drawChars(txt,0,txt.length,30,py+line-5);

    return (py+line);
    }

static private final Font                      font=new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN,16);
static private final int                       line=25;

static public void main(String[] args) {
    Frame                               wnd=new Frame("AWT Antialiased Text Sample");

    wnd.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    wnd.add(new AwtTestFrame1c());
    wnd.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 300));
    wnd.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 I'm also very curious about this

Comment: Update: This seems to have been fixed now. I just tested the program (Oracle JDK 1.7.0_02 on Linux x86), and the text is rendered identically and with subpixel rendering on both lines. The circle is drawn using grayscale AA above and without AA below, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of poking around found this: [bug 6263951](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6263951).

Apparently the bustage is fixed in b17?  I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the bug report.

Definitely broken here on 1.6.0_17-b04 (MacOS X 10.5).

Comment: Hmmm.  Certainly describes the same problem.  I am not sure how to interpret the fix version either - maybe Java 7 build 17?  The bug report is from 2005 and it's certainly still doing this in Java 6_18. Seems strange that it took them 5 years to fix this, since it's a bit of a pain to work around.

Comment: Accepting this because (a) it seems the answer to my question is "yes", and (b) the bug report seems to answer when the fix will be available (that is, eventually, when and if Java 7 ever comes out).

Answer (score 2):

I was updating [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), so I took pictures. I may just be seeing the host's rendering, but I suspect it is also implementation dependent.

Ubuntu 9.10[image: AwtTestFrame Ubuntu]

Mac OS X 10.5[image: AwtTestFrame Mac]

Windows 7[image: AwtTestFrame WIn]

Comment: Good thanks; here you can see that where subpixel AA is used (note the tell-tale color artifacts) the circle is not AA, but where the circle is AA, the text is standard AA instead of subpixel.

Comment: Aha! At least now I see the problem. Sorry I don't have the answer :-)